# EC2: Downgrade m1.small to t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to downgrade our m1.small instance to the new t2.micro instance.

When the instance is stopped, and I try to change instance type, it will not display the t2.micro as an option.

I suspect it has to do with the new way the t2 instances virtualize (PV vs. HMV).

Anyone has an idea on how to perform the downgrade? Is it necessary to take a snapshot/image of the m1.small instance, and start a new t2.micro instance?

Comment: All of the details and limitations are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html

Comment: Thank you for this resource, so as far as I found out, I need to change the virtualization method from PV to HMV (as t2.micro does not support Paravirtualization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [complete guide](http://jsianes.blogspot.in/2014/07/aws-convert-t1-instances-to-t2.html) which you can use to change your existing PV instance to HVM instance. Just follow the steps carefully and you would be able to do it.  Create an Image of your existing instance before you follow the guide

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Okay, so after a few minutes of trying stuff in the AWS dashboard, I found the following solution. For anyone having the same problem, please perform the following steps:</strike>

1. create a snapshot of your PV-based instance (in my case, m1.small).
2. select your snapshot, and choose "create image". then, you can select the option to create a HMV-based image (which is needed for my case, as t2.micro only supports HMV).
3. Launch a new HMV-based instance (for example t2.micro) from your newly created image.

Hope somebody finds this useful! :-)

This does not seem to work, as the instance crashes when trying to be launched using the AMI.

```
Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown
```

Anyone has an idea on how to perform the downgrade / change PV->HMV?

Comment: Had the same thing. We gave up since this is somewhere between impossible and fiddling with a lot of low level stuff, if your base AMI doesn't support the right virtualization. And you should be able to rebuild images anyway (Chef, Puppet, Ansible, Salt,...)

Comment: Yes, it seems it's not possible to downgrade in our case. We simply created a fresh hardware-virtualized t2-instance and moved our app to the new instance manually. Then, we terminated the now obsolete m1.small instance. From now on we'll be able to use our custom AMI to spin up new instances.